# Map methods return List<List<Object>> Instead of List<Object>

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final listTruckFruits = event.trucks
        .map((truck) => truck.fruits
            .map(
              (fruit) => TruckFruit(
                truckOrigin: truck.info.origin,
                fruitType: fruit.type,
              ),
            )
            .toList())
        .toList();
```

I'm trying to map multiple `List<Fruit>` from `List<Truck>`

```
class Truck {
  final List<Fruit> fruits;

  Truck({
    required this.fruits,
  });
}

class Fruit {
  final String type;
  Fruit({
    required this.type,
  });
}
```

into a `List<TruckFruit>`  but currently what is returned from my two map methods `listTruckFruits` **all above** is a `List<List<TruckFruit>>` while a want `List<TruckFruit>`

```dart
class TruckFruit {
  final String fruitType;
  final String truckOrigin;

  TruckFruit({
    required this.fruitType,
    required this.truckOrigin,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Iterable.expand()` to flatten your list of lists:

```
final simpleListOfAllFruitsOnAllTrucks = listTruckFruits.expand((x) => x).toList();
```

You could also use this to not generate a list of lists in the first place, by using it on your `event.trucks` instead of your first `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fold`:

```
  final result = event.trucks.fold<List<TruckFruit>>([], (acc, truck) {
    acc.addAll(truck.fruits
        .map((f) => TruckFruit(truckOrigin: truck.origin, fruitType: f.type)));
    return acc;
  });
```

Comment: is it better or is it as good ? : ) 